# Ubuntu Grub Screen Problems

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I'm running Windows XP and Ubuntu 11.10 as a dual boot, however, at the grub screen, the only way to boot Ubuntu is to select recovery mode and then select resume normal boot.

If I select the proper way to boot Ubuntu however, the screen goes black and then after a while goes to a screen with some text that looks like a terminal screen.

How do I make it so this does not happen?

I just installed it using the disk I had made back when I dual booted my other computer awhile back, and I just partioned my disks in the setup.

When I'm in the text mode I think it is fully functional because when I go Ctrl + Alt + F1 it gives me the option to login, but its all text based.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some problems with /etc/default/grub.  So start up with your recovery mode an then select resume normal boot.  Go to the terminal, type sudo nautilus.
Go to /etc/default/grub and open it. Search for the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and put # in the first position of the line.  Then type or copy this line : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-24, mtrr=3, scroll=ywrap"

Save it, close and come back to terminal.  Then in the terminal sudo update-grub.  And restart. If not working fine, you have to return to  /etc/default/grub and chage mode_option=800x600-24 to the values of you display.  Do not forget afterxard to do sudo update-grub.

Answer (score 0):

There is a graphical tool for repairing the boot process, including Grub, called Boot-Repair.  The website on Launchpad is here, and there is a lot about it: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/.  To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-add update
sudo apt-add install boot-repair
```

I have used this tool quite a few times, always with success, although after it completes its job I always open a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`, just in case